# Swift SpriteKit presentScene error

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to make a asteroids type game, and every time the asteroid collides with the player the end scene loads fine, cut when I try to restart its like the code is stuck looping the collision function that called the end scene. Here is the collision function

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    print("5")
    //Creating a variable that holds which two items collide
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
    //Creating a switch case statement
    //This will run a different case depending on whitch two objects collide
    switch(contactMask) {
    //If the satellite and the asteroid collide do this
    case bitMask.satellite.rawValue | bitMask.asteroid.rawValue:
        //removing the satellite
        let secondNode = contact.bodyB.node
        secondNode?.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        let firstNode = contact.bodyA.node
        firstNode?.removeFromParent()
        //Stopping the mission timer
        removeActionForKey("missionDurationTime")
        self.removeAllChildren()
        print("6")
        self.view?.presentScene(EndScene())
        print("7")
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

And here is the function that goes back to my game scene from my end scene

```
func Restart(){
    print("hello")
    RestartBtn.removeFromSuperview()
    speach.removeFromSuperview()
    score.removeFromSuperview()
    gameOver.removeFromSuperview()
    self.view?.presentScene(GameScene())

}
```

After I hit the restart button all of the labels in the EndScene go away like they should but then the screen is blank and the console just prints `5
 6
 7
Too many times to count until the labels in the end scene come back. I am very confused and in way over my head. Any help is much appreciated!

UPDATE:

I changed the code in my restart button to this

```
print("hello")
    RestartBtn.removeFromSuperview()
    speach.removeFromSuperview()
    score.removeFromSuperview()
    gameOver.removeFromSuperview()
    let scene =  GameScene(size: self.view!.bounds.size)
    scene.backgroundColor = SKColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let transition = SKTransition.pushWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Left, duration:0.5)
    self.scene?.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
```

Now the game scene loads and everything is as it should be, except for the fact that everything is five times bigger. This is what it should look like:
[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4ZVI.png)

And this is what it looks like
[What it does look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcWgC.png)

Comment: How are you calling your first scene when your app launches (code in gameView controller)?. Can you put that code into your question please. In your current restart code you care initialising the GameScene with the view bounds as its size. The  scale mode line 2 lines below will not work when doing this because you are not scaling your scene anymore. I assume you are resizing your scene differently when you load your game and when you restart it and therefore it looks different.

Comment: I'm just using the code in the game view controller that Xcode gives you if that makes sense. I can't post the exact code right now I'm away from my Mac.

Comment: I added an answer. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

In you restart code you are initialising the GameScene with a size of view.bounds.

If you have not changed your GameViewController code than by default you are using the GameScene.sks file as reference (visual level editor) with a default scene size of 1024*768 and scale mode .AspectFill.

In short in your restart function try this

```
 if let scene =  GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") { // fileNamed is the GameScene.sks file
     scene.backgroundColor = SKColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1) 
      ....


 }
```

or alternatively

```
 let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 1024, height: 768)
 scene.backgroundColor ....
```

Comment: Will this work on all screen sizes? Can't try it right now just thinking ahead

Comment: Yeah using aspectFill is the best solution for most cases, it depends what you are making. Generally the idea is that you position your stuff in your game towards the center and just have some extra space on the sides/top/bottom when running on an iPad (in your case just some more space background). Have a look at this http://blog.infinitecortex.com/2014/01/spritekit-understanding-skscene-scalemode/

Comment: It wanted me to put commas after each scene.thing and then it said variable  used within its own initial value

Comment: Awesome. Happy coding and please could you mark as answered if you be so kind.